# opposite operation to dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-cast

I have a base class and derivative class, e.g :

```
class Base {
 public:
  Base();
  virtual doSomthing();
};

class Derivative : class Base {
 public:
  Derivative();
  virtual doSomthing();
};
```

I know that if I want to change at runtime from the father to son I will do

```
Derivative& newDer = dynamic_cast<Derivative&>(baseInstance)
```

my question is how I can do the opposite operation - 
change from son to the father?

Comment: There's no specific cast operation needed. The compiler resolves that automatically.

Comment: What is the reason you need to do this, a derived class has all the properties of it's base. And there normally is an implicit derived-to-base conversion happening at compile-time when you create a pointer or reference to a base class, but assign a derived class.

Comment: You can simply assign. A Derivate **is a** Base.

Comment: `Base &base = some_derivative` will do it.

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a replacement for a good beginner book.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) And your question is a strong indication you have yet to read one.

Comment: @peter _"...  will do it"_ Not with the current example code.

Comment: @user0042.   The current example code would not compile, so that's a moot point.   If the base class is accessible (e.g. inheritance is `public`, or the conversion is being done by a `friend`) the conversion of references from derivative to base is implicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific cast operation needed. Any `Derivative&` automatically can be passed for a `Base&` if they are really have that relation like in

```
class Derivative : public Base {
                // ^^^^^^
 public:
  Derivative();
  virtual doSomthing();
};
```

Supposed you tried to do that from a global `public` scope.

---

> my question is how I can do the opposite operation - change from son to the father?

The inheritance relation needs to be accessible in the scope used though. Your example has `private` inheritance, and it won't work at the `public` scope.

[As mentioned by @StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46255071/opposite-operation-to-dynamic-cast#comment79473720_46255117) and [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46255071/opposite-operation-to-dynamic-cast/46255117?noredirect=1#comment79473844_46255117) it will work at the `Derivative` inner class scope with any class member function or `friend`ed function/class.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a public base, only accessible at the scope where the binding occurs.

Comment: @StoryTeller Doesn't work with `private` inheritance though.

Comment: Of course it does. Any member function can pass `*this` to a function expecting a `Base&`, to name one option.

Comment: @StoryTeller So far I didn't say anything different.

Comment: It also works for a `friend` too.   A friend can convert a derived class reference to base, even if the inheritance is `private`   (assuming, of course, that the conversion is unambiguous).

Comment: @Peter Sure, there are a number of cases it works with `private` inheritance. I just assumed the OP tried from the global `public` scope.